# How to install check:i386 on amd64 debian stretch?

Tags: debian, apt, x86

I have a problem with amd64 Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) virtualbox vm. I want to use 32 bit version of libcheck (C unit test framework), because the program I test must be compiled as 32 bit, so currently build fails like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheck.a when searching for -lcheck
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcheck
```

To install 32 bit version of libcheck I did:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc-multilib
apt-get install check:i386
```

The last command says:

```
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 check:i386 : Depends: libsubunit-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I keep feeding it what it wants I eventually come to this:

```
sudo apt-get install check:i386 libsubunit-dev:i386 libsubunit0:i386 libc6:i386 install-info:i386 libgcc1:i386 gcc-6-base:i386
```

after which it says it'll install what I want but remove half the system (1766 packages) and asks to type in 'Yes, do as I say!'. This is obviously not right. My questions are:

1. What do I do wrong?
2. How do I approach understanding what apt wants?

I am pretty sure it's supposed to work, since if I enable testing in sources.list it installs gcc 7 and everything is ok. The problem is I don't want testing on this vm, so I reverted its state to stretch.

Comment: Does it work any better if you remove `libsubunit-dev` first? (Without removing anything vital...)

Comment: I can confirm that on a freshly-installed Stretch amd64 VM, `dpkg --add-architecture i386; apt-get update; apt-get install gcc-multilib check:i386` works. So it's some existing package you have making a conflict...

Comment: No, removing libsubunit-dev doesn't change a thing.

@derobert: How do I know which package is it? I may have done some experiments with testing but to my knowledge reverted everything. Sadly I don't have saved state.

Comment: @user7231 I'd try `apt install check:i386` (note `apt` instead of `apt-get`); see if that gives a better hint as to what's broken. `aptitude` may also help, as you can explore through the conflicting packages manually. `apt-show-versions` (which you may need to install) can also help find packages from testing, if you have any installed. Alternatively, since its a VM—maybe the easiest thing to do is just install a new VM. Depends on how customized it is, of course. (Ultimately, this leads to things like Docker where you do each and every build in a fresh install).

Comment: @derobert apt says about the same, aptitude suggests multiple solutions all of which involve either not installing check or removing half the system, apt-show-versions I wasn't able to install yet. I think you're right and it's easiest to reinstall. I can't believe I've messed it up so fast though. Was stupid of me not to keep virgin state. Anyway, will update the post when finished with reinstalling.

Comment: @user7231 It is unfortunately fairly easy to get apt confused if you mix stable and testing. It's generally possibly to fix, but apt really hates downgrading packages—so when the right answer is really "downgrade this package from testing back to stable", apt tries very hard to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in a mixed stretch+testing system, after I downgraded a number of libc-related packages everything worked. So the procedure for installing check:i386 which I described is correct, it's just the system was messed up. Thanks to derobert for the guidance.